# MySQL Variables in Eloquent Query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a question about Eloquent Builder in Laravel

```
$query = EntryUserVote::query()
                      ->join('users', 'challenge_entry.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                      ->groupBy(['user_id'])
                      ->select([
                          'users.id as user_id',
                          'users.name as username',
                          DB::raw('count(*) AS amount'),
                          DB::raw("@row := @row + 1 as position")
                      ])
                      ->orderBy('amount', 'desc');
```

I have that Query in my repo and I need to basically add a "rank" which is what that `position` variable refers to, but I need to know how to initialize the variable in Eloquent. Doesn't make sense to do a `from` call since I'm already defining the table through the Eloquent Model...

How would you guys do this? A seperate **SET** statement?

Comment: Still don't understand what's the final purpose. An update statement?

Comment: No no, it's a select, that `$query` variable later goes through a `get()` call. The thing is i need to select the `user_id` and `username` as well as an `amount` and i want a ranking from 1 for the highest amount to X to the lowest. And that "ranking" is what the variable is for since MySQL doesn't support RowNumber or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can intialize the variable using the `set` keyword in a raw statement :

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('set @row=0'));
$query = EntryUserVote::query()
                      ->join('users', 'challenge_entry.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                      ->groupBy(['user_id'])
                      ->select([
                          'users.id as user_id',
                          'users.name as username',
                          DB::raw('count(*) AS amount'),
                          DB::raw("@row := @row + 1 as position")
                      ])
                      ->orderBy('amount', 'desc');
```

Comment: for some reason the positions don't obey the orderBy, they're all over the place, the IDs are ordered by the amount but the position doesn't obey that order at all, i don't know why